# Want to build a app to monitor Imilab TG-1 smartwatch data

Tags: android, bluetooth, sony-smartwatch

i want to make a Fitnes tracker app. I have a smartwatch of imilab. Now i want to know, how do i communicate with my smartwatch via Bluetooth to get the data.

i have asked gpt , it says about protocol documentation which i couldnt found.  Can anyone help me ?

NOTE: It is not a android smartwatch. It is not running on wear os.

Comment: Contact imilab and ask them.

Comment: I have yet to see one wearable that simply offers it's data to everyone who wants to read it. Please start by scanning the smartwatch using a generic BLE exploration tool such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) to see if it is able to detect some standard services to work with. You can then try to read data from the watch, but I would guess that this would be to no avail without propper documentation of the watches services